# Stripe Returning the Wrong priceId When Using productObject

Tags: stripe-payments

I was creating a Stripe checkout session using a priceId like this, which was working fine

```
router.post(
  '/create-checkout-session',
  auth,
  async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res) => {
    try {
      const { prod_id } = req.body

      const productObject = await Stripe.products.retrieve(prod_id)



      const session = await Stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: 'subscription',


        metadata: {
          userId: req.userId,
        },

        line_items: [
          {
            price: productObject.default_price,
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],

        success_url: `${url}` + "/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'",
        cancel_url: `${url}` + '/cancelled',
      })

      res.json({ url: session.url })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res
        .status(HttpStatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json({ msg: 'Server Error.' })
    }
  }
)
```

Now I'm creating a Stripe checkout session for my clients using Stripe Connect like this. However, I'm getting the wrong priceId when I access it in this manner

```
router.post('/create-checkout-session/connectedaccount/:projectId', auth, async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res) => {
  
 
  try {
    const { prod_id, connected_stripe_account_id} = req.body;

    const productObject = await Stripe.products.retrieve(prod_id);

    const priceId = productObject.default_price;

    console.log("priceId", priceId)

    if (!priceId) {
      return res.status(HttpStatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: 'Couldnt locate the priceID' })
    }

    try {

      const customer = await Stripe.customers.create({
        description: 'Customer for connected subscription',
      }, {
        stripeAccount: connected_stripe_account_id,
      });
    
      // Create a subscription using the new customer ID
      const subscription = await Stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: customer.id,
        items: [{ price: priceId }],
        expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
      }, {
        stripeAccount: connected_stripe_account_id,
      });
    
      console.log(subscription);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }


    const session = await Stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: `${url}/success/connected-account?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${url}/connected-account/cancelled`,
    },{
      stripeAccount: connected_stripe_account_id,
    });

    res.json({ url: session.url });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Stripe Checkout Session Error:', error);
    res
      .status(HttpStatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
      .json({ msg: 'Server Error. Please contact support immediately' });
  }
});
```

I'm gettint this error

```
Error: StripeInvalidRequestError: No such price: 'price_1mxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
```

When I checked the product page, I noticed that there is no 'price_1mxxxxxxxxxxxx' on the dashboard either. I don't understand how Stripe is picking this random value priceId from productId for Stripe Connect.

```
const productObject = await Stripe.products.retrieve(prod_id);

const priceId = productObject.default_price;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you retrieve the Product on the Platform account (sending request without `stripeAccount` header), and then creating the Checkout Session on the Connected account (with `stripeAccount` header). To fix this, add `{ stripeAccount: 'acct_xxx' }` to your call to get the Product:

```
await Stripe.products.retrieve(prod_id, {}, {
  stripeAccount: 'acct_xxx'
})
```

Note, I see you're sending the Product ID from the frontend, make sure this is an ID of a Product object that exists on the Connected account too. You can't reuse objects across Stripe accounts.